# I would like to check a SQL query of Laravel builder

Tags: laravel

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toSql does not exist.

occured when I tried this

My laravel version 6.20

```
$query =  Car::where($criteria)
->get(['id'])->shuffle();

$sql = $query->toSql();

Log::info($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the query using **get()** it will return an instance of **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection** class. And there's no method named **toSql()** on the Collection class.

If you want to inspect the sql you should

```php
$query =  Car::where($criteria)->select('id');

//Here $query is an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
//And it has a method named toSql
$sql = $query->toSql();

Log::info($sql);

$query->get()->shuffle();
```